# IsolatedStorageFile.GetLastAccessTime is crashing on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

It sounds like "An error occurred while accessing IsolatedStorage". But there's no such exceptions is msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getlastaccesstime(v=vs.110).aspx

I assume, it can be because i'm calling it inside of Task.Factory.StartNew(). Can it be a reason? It works on wp8 fine.

**EDIT:**

The problem was that I used `GetLastAccessTime(cacheFileName).Millisecond;` As it is said by the link by Agat, miliseconds are always 0 at the wp7. Or, actually, they are even not available, because exception is throwing while trying to access them. So just dont use Milliseconds, and that's it.

Comment: Is that a steady exception or occurs only from time to time?

Comment: @Agat it appears always. On wp8 it returns real time, but on wp7 it is always 0.

Comment: What's about any inner exceptions and what is the actual name of the top one?

Comment: @Agat it is looking like http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1384008861-clip-47kb.png The problem is that it always returns 0 for wp7, and some data for wp8.

Comment: Still, try to lock the access for such operations, plus, I am not sure if I can "trust" the cacheFileName from the screenshot. he he

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just asking **if it can** be? I would rather answer that "**yes, it can**", and generally, because [of the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769544%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> To synchronize access to the local folder between different threads,
>   we recommend using the Mutex class. A mutex grants exclusive access to
>   a shared resource to only one thread. If one thread acquires a mutex,
>   the second thread that wants to acquire that mutex is suspended until
>   the first thread releases the mutex. For example, a mutex could be
>   used to synchronize access to a folder between a Windows Phone app
>   running in the foreground and a background agent.

*But from other hands, if the exception occurs constantly, there might be a number of other reasons. Please have a look at **[this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/25e33fe3-f930-41df-bb82-a6ec2acee75a/bug-getlastaccesstime-does-not-report-correct-access-time-for-a-file-in-isolated-storage-on-windows)**, which can give you a clue about some specific things of GetLastAccessTime method work on Windows Phone 7.*

Comment: Yes, it appears constantly, on every call.

Comment: Thanks a tons! Indeed, miliseconds are always zeroed in wp7. Wondering, why it is not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Hm... But you've mentioned something about error? Because if the method just returns 0, that might embarrasse another users which would start reading this question.

Comment: it is not just returning zero. Is also throws an exception if to try to get Milliseconds.

Comment: Aha. Well, that might be strange. However, anyway, I would still recommend you to use safe multithreading for such things. Slava Ukrajini! :)